# What is the purpose of using "+=" instead of "=" in java?

Tags: java

So I ran into this piece of code today while working on an existing codebase. My question is why the assignment operator was not used here.

```
  int getSum(int mVar) {
      int sum = 0;
      sum += ((mVar != null) ? mVar : 0);
      return sum;
    }
```

It appears an assignment operator would suffice:

```
int getSum(int mVar) {
      int sum = ((mVar != null) ? mVar : 0);
      return sum;
    }
```

Is there any benefit to initializing the value to zero?

Comment: `sum += mVar` is the same as `sum = sum + mVar`

Comment: It is shorter more readable...

Comment: How would you have used _just_ the assignment operator to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: Assignment operator (=) assign value. += on the other hand is an add operation.

Comment: all a matter of preference plus any rules in your company, managers rules, etc. Some make you code in a certain style such as instead of doing `i = i+1` you have to always put `i++` and vice versa. But normally short hands make the code easier to read. And is very helpful when dealing with thousands of line of code.

Comment: I think my question is not clear. I mean couldn't we just use `sum = ((mVar != null) ? mVar : 0)` instead of `sum += ((mVar != null) ? mVar : 0)`

Comment: Honestly, +=, -= etc are legacy from c from a time when coders would use this to operate directly on processor register values, rather than doing a few memory get and put each time. At this point, they are syntactic sugar, and I try to avoid them for readability purposes (other commenters have already posted preference for this as more readable though)

Comment: I think OP is asking why += and not = because `sum` is assigned 0 and thus the result is the same ...

Comment: Note that this code won't compile. An `int` variable cannot hold `null`.

Comment: Y'all are wrong. look at my answer, you are mistaking the OP for not even understanding what += means, but instead he's wondering why it's even used here. In fact, he's right "why is assignment not used here". It should be.

Comment: in addition, java primitive int can never be null....

Comment: @jgr208 ... short hands make code easier to read ... I disagree. For instance, I've always struggled with the difference between i++ and ++i. I believe that less syntax makes programming languages easier to read

Comment: @ControlAltDel if you have seen some of the stuff i have seen that people did without using short hands in code such as on line 2 `i=0` on line 500 `j=1` then line 2000 `i=i+j` in a for loop. But I also get what you mean, since that example is also just bad use of memory and all something shorthand will make easier but could have been easy from the get go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To answer your question, in this example there is no point in using "+=", a regular assignment operator is better**

```
 int getSum(int mVar) {
      int sum = 0;
      sum += ((mVar != null) ? mVar : 0);
      return sum;
 }
```

This code is a bad example of "+=" because it shouldn't be used here. Instead it should be:

```
   int getSum(Integer mVar) {
          return mVar != null? mvar : 0;
   }
```

You don't see the benefit of "+=" because `sum` is already `0`. So, you look at it and you're wondering why you would do `sum = 0 + mVar;` (which is the same as saying `sum += mVar` when you can do `sum = mVar;`

A better example is (ofc these values probably don't make sense, but it makes the "+=" valuable):

```
  int getSum(int mVar) {
          int sum = 5;
          sum += ((mVar != null) ? mVar : 10);
          return sum;
     }
```

This way if you don't use "+=" you are forced in saying `sum = sum + mVar;` or else it wouldn't be correct.

Comment: i think it was because you openly insulted someone in this answer which has no need to do that.

Comment: @jgr208 openly insulted, how? Saying someone was interpreting the OP wrong, so they downvoted him too? if anything "downvoting" someone as revenge should be reportable

Comment: by saying that is a bad example in your answer instead of just adding that as a comment to his question. but yes i agree however with out rep we will never know who did it so eh nothing to do about it.

Comment: i prefer "correcting" someone, not sure how telling someone that they are wrong is insulting. if you get offended from someone telling you that you are wrong then you are going to have a lot of trouble learning my friend.

Comment: @BrandonLing thanks for actually reading / understanding the question. People directly assumed I didn't know the += operator. It was kind of funny to see how they try to explain how the operator works.

Comment: Your welcome, and sorry on behalf of all the stackoverflow users who assumed too quickly what you were asking. Couldn't agree more, it was kinda silly

Answer (score 4):

This

```
int getSum(int mVar) {
    int sum = 0;
    sum += ((mVar != null) ? mVar : 0);
    return sum;
}
```

is the same as

```
int getSum(int mVar) {
    int sum = 0;
    if( mVar != null ) {
        sum = sum + mVar;
    } else {
        sum = sum + 0;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

It's just full of shorthand code. :)

As many of the comments mentioned, `a += b` is just the same as `a = a + b`. It's a nifty trick to have. The same also applies for `a -= b`, `a *= b`, and `a /= b`.

If you were curious, `(mVar != null) ? mVar : 0;` is a ternary operator. It goes like `condition ? value if true : value if false;` and is usually used for assignments.

Some notes though. An `int` is a primitive data type that can never be null, so **the code above is just for the sake of explaining syntax.**

Comment: the method could be shortened still to just `return ((mVar != null) ? mVar : 0);`

Comment: Yes, but I think the whole point of the answer is to explain the syntax. :)

Comment: OP did not understand why `+=` was used and not the normal `=` assignment, so it was explained. He wasn't asking how to shorten/optimize the code.

Comment: @theguywhodreams I have a hunch that this is not the answer the OP is looking for. When sum is set to 0, it completely defeats the purpose of saying sum += mVar; sum = mVar is the exact same. 0 = 0 + value is the same as 0 = value. The OP is probably wondering why assignment operator isn't used in this scenario (which he would be correct in wondering)